# Need a regular expression that will extract first 7 or 8 characters of string that ends with specific characters

Tags: regex, splunk, text-extraction

First timer here and would greatly appreciate any assistance. Need the regular expression to get the first 7 or 8 characters of variable length strings that end with abcd.com. Example below:

```
tpbjm01-re0.abcd.com
xtsdjm01-re0.abcd.com
lnd2j902-re1.abcd.com
pqrjm02-re1.abcd.com
py3jm01-re1.uk.abcd.com
brhmjm02-re1.emea.abcd.com
rcnj902.abcd.com
cpzyjm01.abcd.com
```

So result should be:

```
tpbjm01
xtsdjm01
lnd2j902
pqrjm02
py3jm01
brhmjm02
rcnj902
cpzyjm01
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: SO is for coding issues. Not for code requests. If you have code add that to the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: `^(\w{7,8}).*?\.abcd\.com$` - https://regex101.com/r/peRzl4/3

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(\w{7,8})(?=.*abcd.com)
```

It will capture 7 or 8 char in the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` at the beginning

Comment: He said ones that end with abcd.com

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne all his entry ends with `abcd.com`. Fixed anyway

Comment: True. But I'd assume he has more entries which don't.

Comment: Thank you for the response. All ends with abcd.com. I am actually extracting router names for syslog messages using splunk. The above regex is not actually pulling anything, the command line I'm using is as follows: rex field=_raw "^(\w{7,8})(?<ROUTER>=.*abcd.com)"

Comment: @NIsargP because your regex is invalid :) `(?=)` is a positive lookahead, not a named capturing group. remove the `<ROUTER>` part and it should work

Comment: I'm sorry, really new to this. Error I am getting: Error in 'rex' command: The regex '^(\w{7,8})(?=.*vzbi.com)' does not extract anything. It should specify at least one named group. Format: (?<name>...).

Comment: `^(?<name>\w{7,8})(?=.*abcd.com)` should be what you need @NIsargP